# What would prevent angular.element().injector() access from browser console when production mode is enabled

Tags: angularjs, developer-console

I did this in my code for the production

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo = angular.noop
```

Due to the above code when I run this script in the browser console then

```
angular.element(document.body).scope() // output undefind
```

For the scope, it's working as expected But the issue is, the injected services are not prevented in the broswer console

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get('TestService')
```

it returns the TestService instance and anyone can update the method implementation etc..
How can we prevent angular.element(document.body).injector() from the browser's console in production mode ???

Answer (score 1):

In the end, you deliver code to be run in the client. So there will always be code delivered into concerns out of your influence, that can be inspected by people who know what they do.

If your concern is about security, you shouldn't rely on client code not being visible. Increasing code obscurity not only fails to make code more secure, sometimes it even makes it worse. The only place, where security related tasks can be run securely is on the server, never on the client, no matter how you obfuscate it.

If your concern is about your intellectual property on the code, the best thing that can be done (if any) is to use some kind of code obfuscation. This will, at least, increase the effort required to backward engineer your code.